# How to change startup command of "dhclient"

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dhcp, apparmor, dhclient

I want to add some extra flags to "dhclient" command running ubuntu 14.04,

dhclient starts at bootup and the default command I get using "ps" is as follows ,

> /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf
>   /run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dhclient-eth0.pid -lf
>   /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-cf3e1c07-94fa-44b7-a44b-5987b9ec596a-eth0.lease

I want to add "-w" flag to this.

I am looking in "/etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient" but couldn't find place where can i add this flag or from where "-d -q" flags are provided to this command.

Answer (score 0):

Under the *Network Manager* settings (which can be accessed by clicking on the *Network* icon on the right-top corner, if you are using Ubuntu-Mate, and then clicking *Edit*), select the connection that you wish to *Edit...* and change the settings as needed.
HTH!

Comment: thanks. but it wan't help because the command is hard coded in ifup/down code. Issue is resolved days ago.